# PHP Ratchet: Class Memcache not found

Tags: php, ratchet

I am following Ratchet's tutorials. For SessionProvider page, the code is like this:

```
<?php
// Your shell script
use Ratchet\Session\SessionProvider;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler;
use Ratchet\App;

$memcache = new Memcache; // Class not found on line 7
$memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

$session = new SessionProvider(
    new MyApp
  , new Handler\MemcacheSessionHandler($memcache)
);

$server = new App('localhost');
$server->route('/sessDemo', $session);
$server->run();
```

PHP throws a fatal error when I run the script in the `command-line`:

> Class Memcache not found in  on line 7

This code is placed in bin\chat-server.php

## Wierd Stuff

The class is not available only for `chat-server.php` script.

Comment: Is it possible that you've executed one of the scripts on the command line and the other one through a web browser?

Comment: You must indeed add the memcache module to PHP CLI. But, sorry, I don't know how to do this on Windows/XAMPP.

Comment: Memcache issue is still there. It is open to answers.

Comment: Then you should update your answer with additional information about your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two *distinct* PHP extensions for the service `memcached`:

- `memcache`
- `memcached` <-- note the `d`

Looks like you have installed the latter one, while you need the first one for your application.

You can find the right extension for Windows [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/)

Comment: Thread-safe extension for Apache, right? Well, I can't award the bounty now. Will try later :D

Comment: If you are using Apache in prefork mode, you can use the `nts` version, meaning *not thread safe*, otherwise use the `ts` (*thread safe*) extension.

Comment: i have the same problem now, how can i install the extensions ?